# Edit consumer key in Fabric

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I integrated twitter using Fabric plugin in iPhone, but Android as different plugin called Twitter 4j. We need to share same consumer key and api key in both android and iPhone. Fabric creates a separate consumer key and api key and is not editable. Can I change the consumer key as same as android in iphone? I used Fabric cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you have a key created through apps.twitter.com, you can use that for your applications unless you want to use Digits or Guest Authentication. If you're looking to use those two, then you need to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io to get the key whitelisted.

The Fabric key is generated for apps when they start using Twitter or Digits, but you can continue to use the one you had created previously.

-Mike

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike! Can I get a documentation link on where should I do the changes?

Comment: Check out the doc on authentication here: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html#authentication